# How can I influence the foreground color of Labels of Xubuntu's desktop icons

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce

I am using Xubuntu 20.04. For some special purpose, I have installed Xubuntu on an USB stick. In order to always remind myself of using this special installation, I have set the background on it to yellow.

However, the label inscriptions are not well legible, since they appear in white on yellow background and also they have bright shadows, which makes the inscription to appear dull. I want the labels to be in black on the yellow background such that they become legible, preferrably without shadow effect.

I have tried other themes than Adwaita, but all themes offered seem to be made for dark screens (which seems to be reasonable on mobile devices with OLED displays, but on a laptop with a classical LCD device, dark themes have no energy saving profit).

There must be some place where one can influence the inscription: I have a similar installation of an earlier Xubuntu on a stick. The desktop background is also yellow there (it was made for the same purpose). I have dark label inscriptions there. But I don't know, how I achieved it or if it was that way from the beginning.

**Which program must I use to access the settings for the color of the label's inscriptions? Is ist xfce4-settings-editor?**

**Which of the many settings (in which category) is responsible for the label-inscriptions?**

**What exactly value do I need for black without shadow?**

Comment: Are you asking for, like, a theme? Or are you trying to customize the look by editing the code?

Comment: I just want to stay with the current theme and don't want to do extensive programming. I hope there is just one place where I can just influence the color of the label and possibly it s shadow casting property.

Comment: Easiest way: set your background to something else than yellow. Likely, changing the font of icons require coding, which you want to avoid.

Comment: If I understand you right, there is nothing to control the color of the font, but there is something to control the color of the background of the label. Since my main concern is legibility rather than beauty, I would not mind seeing the labels with white color on black backgrounds (just around the labels). But where exactly can I access this feature?

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies for Xubuntu 22.04 and possibly it does not apply to older versions, because according to https://news.itsfoss.com/xfce-4-16-release/ Xfce 4.16 drops the Gtk 2 support code and adds dependency for GTK 3.22 or above.

I succeeded to display desktop icons with black label and without shadows on my uniform yellow desktop background by this entry in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```
v@g:~/.config/gtk-3.0$ cat gtk.css
XfdesktopIconView.label {
color: #000000;
text-shadow: none;
}
v@g:~/.config/gtk-3.0$
```

[image: desktop icon on yellow backdrop with black label]